# Creating a automatic login javascript for logging into web application

Tags: javascript, authentication

I need to create a login javascript which I can save as a bookmark in my bookmarks toolbar in the browser and when I run it.. It should log me into my web application which is set up locally for my development purposes.
The idea is basically to remove the hassle to enter username and password repeatedly for logging into the web app for testing etc..
We had this done previously by some one in my last workplace, but just want to do it myself now.

Comment: Why not just save the username/password into the browser?

Comment: if you have done it before, just do it again.

Answer (score -1):

You do better when you use COOKIES.

But if you want so, then construct link like:

```
javascript:location.href='http://my_host/my_system?autoLogin=1&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD'
```

Hope this is what you want but you need to optimize your system to be able to parse link like this.
Also I suggest using hashed (1-way encrypted) password.

Comment: using a hash is totally useless. how do you intend to validate the hash? `sent hash == stored hash`? it's like knowing the password.

Comment: Using a hash is totaly useless ? That's actually totally incorrect argument. Hashing is one-way irreversible process in which you get unique non-readable and I repeat irreversible representation of plain text string. Means you can break it only using bruteforce.

Comment: then tell me how do you intend to validate that hash? if i knew the hash, no matter how "secure" and "irreversible" the hash is, that does not stop me from using it according to your answer.

Comment: Exactly as you said "sent hash == stored hash". But you are telling that knowing hash is like knowing password. And that's actually wrong.

Comment: if someone knew the username and the hash, would your hash stop that someone from accessing the account? where's your security now?

Comment: No, but it would stop somebody from knowing someone password, which is much personal and extremely unsafe thing. I'm not telling that knowledge of hash can't lead to unwanted access. But I am telling that it is better to know hash than know the password.

Comment: then how different is your hash from a password ***if it's used in the same way?***

Comment: Okay, then. Go through everything I wrote in these comments. And try to find out what I meant. It's not about programming - it's about personal security. And that's last thing I am gonna say.

Comment: [password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) is used during storage, **not for login, not for transport**